# Why does linux multiarch use x86_64-linux-gnu instead of lib64?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shared-libraries, debian-based

I recently came across multiarch in linux when deploying 32 & 64bit libraries.

Out of curiosity, why was /lib64 abandoned in favour of e.g. /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
It seems overly complex but there must be a reason for that.

Comment: It is the host triplet as given (i.e. guessed) by `configure`; it take into account the ABI; for instance x32 is a different ABI for x86-64.

Comment: When was it - I have not noticed - how did you find that?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Some distros have adopted the Debian multiarch layout, others still use lib64.

Comment: @janneb Cool. - Debian was never one of the distros I liked. Adding is not lib and lib64 a multiarch layout anyways

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Sorry, I don't know what "Adding is not lib and lib64 a multiarch layout anyways" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long version can be found at http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch , in particular http://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/TheCaseForMultiarch .

The short version is that using triplets is a more general solution that allows things like multiple ABI's (such as x86 and x32, as Basile mentioned in a comment), emulators, cross-compilers and such without having to resort to various tricks.

Whether non-Debian based distros such as Fedora or OpenSUSE will adopt this remains to be seen; so far they don't seem that interested.