# How to persuade dynamic loader to respect $LIB within RPATH in linux?

Tags: linux, dynamic-loading, rpath

I have set the binary's rpath to the following: `/usr/$LIB/test:$ORIGIN/lib/`

The libraries are located at `/usr/lib64/test`, but when I run my binary it says it can't find those libraries.

I have checked the rpath with `readelf -d`.

The question is simple - why?

---

### Upgrade #1

**OS**: Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
**ld version**: 2.15

Comment: I don't believe you can use shell variable expansion in rpath. Use real paths.

Comment: @keltar read `man 8 ld.so`

Comment: Ouch, haven't knew that, tried with ordinary variables. ORIGIN works for me, try `ldd ./your_program` and add output to question if you'll find anything unusual.

Comment: @keltar the `ldd` just shows `not found` for my libs. And the question is about the `$LIB` part.

Comment: What's your version of ld.so? `ls -l /lib64/ld-linux-x86_64.so.2` - it's the number e.g. `ld-2.17.so`, if it's smaller than 2.3.2, then it implies you don't have `$LIB` variable expansion available as it was introduced in that version. `$ORIGIN` and `$PLATFORM` were introduced in 2.1

Comment: There are also some rules for setuid executables (only bareword `$ORIGIN` is permitted/interpreted)

Comment: @Petesh `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so`

Comment: What distro? On my debian `$LIB` gets expanded to `lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (so, `/usr/$LIB` becomes `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`)

Comment: @keltar How do you know what is an expansion? Also, I have updated question.

Comment: @abyss.7 I know no way to query that, sorry. All I know is that in amd64 debian system libraries are placed in `/usr/lib/<architecture_name>`, so I've tried that and it worked. At home I have gentoo, which uses `/usr/lib64` - it works quite well in *this* directory too. The thing is, $LIB is different between distros. As for ubuntu, I don't have it at the moment, so can't check that.

Comment: This seems to be an explanation as to the why, but doesn't really help in determining the what: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312053/why-does-linux-multiarch-use-x86-64-linux-gnu-instead-of-lib64